# Are tkinter buttons able to run if statement once pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on a project for school and was wondering whether I was able to have the button linked to an if statement which is inside a while loop. This would mean that my program would write to a file dependent on which button was pressed. I have all of this running in a function to make it global so the files are appended anytime. I was also trying to save me the time of having to make other functions for things like callback or button pressed.

```
x = 1
while x == 1:

    if mainnav == True:
        file = open(usrnametext.get() + '.account', 'a')

        info = (usernametext.get() + passwrdtext.get())

        file.write("Register/Login" + "\n")
        file.write(info + "\n")
        file.write(daofbitxt.get() + "\n")
        file.write(emailtext.get() + "\n")
        file.write(heighttext.get())
        file.close()

        print("File successfully written")
        print("Continuing to main page")
```

Here's just a quick example of what I mean. mainnav is a button that when pressed will write the users account.

Comment: Just go ahead and make the callback functions -- that's how Tkinter buttons are designed to work (with the `callback=` argument) and there's really no time saved in "fighting city hall" to try and make them work completely differently!

Comment: @AlexMartelli: rather, `command=`.

Comment: @jsbueno, you're right -- a "thinko" on my part and of course I can't edit the comment any more.  Memo to self: _always_ double check the docs (esp. before commenting -- answers can be edited:-) no matter how sure you are you remember details correctly!-)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote example, dummy code, showing how you could use few buttons, and do something depending which one is pressed:

```
from tkinter import *


class TestFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)


        self.btns = []

        self.btns.append(Button(self, text="Option 0", command = lambda: self._callback(0)))
        self.btns.append(Button(self, text="Option 1", command = lambda: self._callback(1)))
        self.btns.append(Button(self, text="Option 2", command = lambda: self._callback(2)))

        for btn in self.btns:
            btn.pack()


        self.pack()

    def _callback(self, b_id):
        print("Pressed Option " + str(b_id))
        # do other stuff based on which button was clicked



root = Tk()

tf = TestFrame(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The code creates a frame with three buttons. And `_callback` prints which button was pressed. So, your if statements go into `_callback` method. Hope this helps.

[image]